# objective-c how to call different values based on user selection of class

Tags: objective-c

i am working on a sort of simulator for a game i am designing and am in need of a bit of help. the basic simulator will run from within GNUstep's compiler via dos i suppose is the best way to describe it. The basic idea is this: when the program loads it will ask to select the ID of a unit from a populated list upon selection it references a class and creates a new class and its methods then it asks for a defending unit ID, and follows the similar path of creating that new class and methods. i apologize if my terminology is wrong on methods and such.

in any case so far all that i want to have happen happens. i can call the new units via entry by using cases.

on to the hard part:

```
@interface Unit1: NSObject {         @interface Unit2: NSObject {

    int unitType;                        int unitType;
    int attackInfantry;                  int attackInfantry;
    int attackArmored;                   int attackArmored;
    int attackAerial;                    int attackAerial;
    int attackAquatic;                   int attackAquatic;
    int attackHeroic;                    int attackHeroic;

    int attackHP;                        int attackHP;
    int attackBAV;                       int attackBAV;
    int attackBDV;                       int attackBDV;
}                                    }
-(void) print;                       -(void) print;
-(void) Stats;                       -(void) Stats;
@end                                 @end
```

so heres an example of my interface we have two units here: Next up is the implementation:

```
@implementation Marine                    @implementation Speeder

-(void) Stats                             -(void) Stats
{                                         {

  attackHP = 10;                            attackHP = 10;
  attackBAV = 20;                           attackBAV = 23;
  attackBDV = 10;                           attackBDV = 10;

  unitType = 1;                             unitType = 2;
  attackInfantry = 15;                      attackInfantry = 23;
  attackArmored = 10;                       attackArmored = 18;
  attackAerial = 0;                         attackAerial = 9;
  attackAquatic = 7;                        attackAquatic = 15;
  attackHeroic = 0;                         attackHeroic = 0;
}                                         }
```

so heres the plan, what i would like to do is have some way of recognizing the unitType and then selecting the proper attack value. so in this case 1 equals infantry and 2 equals armored. for this example the first unit would be using attackArmored = 10; because the program recognizes that the second unit has unitType = 2; and the second unit would use attackInfantry = 23; for the same reason, it knows that it is attacking an infantry type unit.

im not sure if i have the units set up as properly as they should be, but im building this simulator with the intent on learning as i am new to objective-C and the world of code.

i hope this all made sense and i was able to get my question across...

Comment: please edit so your code is clearly indented.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like both `Unit1` (should probably be `InfantryUnit`) and `Unit2` (should probably be `SpeederUnit`) should have an abstract parent called `Unit`.  All the properties (`attackHP`, etc) would be defined in `Unit`.

The `-init` method of each subclass of `Unit` would set up the hit points, attack values, etc of that particular unit.

I would also have a method on `Unit` that goes something like this:

```
typedef enum {
  UnitTypeInfantry = 1,
  UnitTypeSpeeder = 2
} UnitType;

+ (Unit *) unitWithType:(UnitType)type {
  if (type == UnitTypeInfantry) {
    return [[[InfantryUnit alloc] init] autorelease];
  } else if (type == UnitTypeSpeeder) {
    return [[[SpeederUnit alloc] init] autorelease];
  }
  return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a bunch of individual attack variables for all the different opponent types, you could make a single variable `attackValues` that's an `NSDictionary`. The keys of the dictionary would be the opponent type, and the values would be the attack amounts. (Another possibility would be to use an `NSArray` indexed by unit type, assuming your types are all small integers, but the key/value approach is more flexible.)

For example,

```
@interface Unit1: NSObject {         

    int unitType;           // numeric type (1, 2, ...)
    NSString *unitTypeName; // "Infantry", "Armored", ...
    NSDictionary *attackValues;                    
...
}  


-init  {
    unitType = UnitTypeInfantry;
    unitTypeName = @"Infantry";

    // Set attack values for other kinds of units
    attackValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:15], @"Infantry",
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], @"Armored",
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"Aerial",
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:7], @"Acquatic",
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"Heroic",
       nil];
}
```

Then to get the attack value for a particular opponent type, all you need to do is:

```
int attack = [[attackValues objectForKey:[opponent unitTypeName]] intValue];
```

The advantages of using a dictionary-driven design instead of individual properties are:

1) You don't have to write a lot of `if` statements like:

```
if (opponent.unitType == 1) 
    attack = attackInfantry; 
else if ((opponent.unitType == 1) 
    attack = attackArmored;
else if ...
```

2) If you add a new unit type, you don't need to add a new variable to every other unit type.

Comment: I like where David is going. +1 for using an NSDictionary in the class to contain units opponents values

Comment: i definitely like where this is going, and i have a decent grasp of the idea, however im a little unsure of where exactly to put all this? im thinking that part of this needs to go into the implementation file